# Допустимо ли задавать настройки сесии каждому USER AGENT отдельно?

Tags: php, сессия

**Преамбула: я чайник, но не тупой.**

**Источник проблемы:** мой сайт использует сессии для хранения "номера дизайна" от которого зависит выбор валюты, картинок и проч. То есть без сессий сайт просто не работает. Не знаю, почему 10 лет не было проблем, но недавно столкнулся с тем, что поисковые роботы открывают сессию на каждую страницу (возможно, раньше они принимали куки, а теперь перестали). В итоге папка с сессиями растет очень быстро. Кроме того, я установил время жизни сессии 14 суток (чтобы не обнулялась корзина у покупателей), и получил проблему с папкой сессий в несколько гигабайт.

**Попытка решения:** Запретил роботам запускать сессии, но роботы стали получать нерабочий сайт. Поэтому сперва я разделил папки сессий реальных юзеров и роботов:

```
if (!is_bool(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Yandex'))) {
    $path_bot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/sessions/bots-yandex';
    ini_set('session.save_path', $path_bot);
}
```

**Вопрос 1.** Правильно ли я понимаю, что ini_set( устанавливает значение переменных типа 'session.save_path' только для конкретного... как его назвать? Процесса? Пользователя? Ну то есть например одновеменно сайт смотрит клиент и по нему идет робот. При этом и тот и другой живут отдельно, для каждого свой набор переменных, если они заданы через РНР ini_set( и друг другу не мешают?

**Вопрос 2.** Не будет ли сказываться негативно на производительность или работу сервера в целом то, что каждое обращение к странице идет проверка ЮЗЕР АГЕНТ и меняется значение 'session.save_path'?

**Вопрос 3.** А что если я кроме 'session.save_path' для робота задам ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $time_live_session); скажем =0 (то есть убивать сразу как ушел) в то время как остальным ЮЗЕР АГЕНТ будет оставаться = 14 суток. Не будет ли конфликтов и противоречий?

**Вопрос 4.** Влияет ли размер папки sessions и количество файлов в ней на производительность? А то у меня там уже больше 1 Гб и сотни тысяч сессий...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: не проще совсем не стартовать роботу сессию?

Comment: Да это я сделал первым делом... Но у меня беда. У меня структура каталогов включает в себя $siteID - движок работает на 4 сайта на разных языках... И айди сайта пишется в сессию (да, знаю, это плохо, но сайту 10 лет и отклик 10 мс, хотя каталог большой и посещаемость нормальная ну и т.п.).
Так вот - не стартую сессию, получаю кучу not exist потому что вместо dir/siteID/pictures выходит соответственно dir//pictures

Answer (score 0):

Плохие новости. Нашел ответ на главный вопрос - **Вопрос 3**.

Сборщик мусора PHP запускается до моих скриптов. Сооветственн оему плевать что я там установил через init_set(). Соответственно он следит только за master (возможно еще и за local) директорией хранения сессий.

Соответственно раздельное управление временем жизни сессий на уровне одного сайта, в зависимости от USER AGENT (да в зависимости от чего бы то ни было) посредством PHP невозможно.

Вариант только один - делать своего сборщика, точнее по одному на каждую директорию. Ничего страшного, если бы я не был тупым юзером.

Answer (score 0):

> поисковые роботы открывают сессию на каждую страницу

Роботы не сохраняют куки. Со сроком жизни сессии в 14 дней - да, будет объёмная директория. А проблема в чём?

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что ini_set( устанавливает значение переменных типа 'session.save_path' только для конкретного... как его назвать?

Только для текущего HTTP-запроса. И настройки сессии может изменить только до `session_start`

> Не будет ли сказываться негативно на производительность или работу сервера в целом то, что каждое обращение к странице идет проверка ЮЗЕР АГЕНТ и меняется значение 'session.save_path'?

Можно пренебречь. Если это критично - значит вы уже давно не используете скриптовые языки и переписали на что-то сильно компилируемое.

> А что если я кроме 'session.save_path' для робота задам ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $time_live_session); скажем =0 (то есть убивать сразу как ушел) в то время как остальным ЮЗЕР АГЕНТ будет оставаться = 14 суток. Не будет ли конфликтов и противоречий?

Сборщик мусора стартует с небольшой вероятностью при вызове `session_start` и работает с теми настройками, которые были на тот момент установлены.

Конфликта не будет, если сборщик будет смотреть в другое место. Просто физически не найдёт сессии рядовых пользователей.

> Влияет ли размер папки sessions и количество файлов в ней на производительность? А то у меня там уже больше 1 Гб и сотни тысяч сессий...

Размер дисковый - влияет, если вы упрётесь в скорость диска. Количество файлов в одной директории - бывает что производительность обращений к этой директории страдает. Измерьте. Если да, страдает - то можно думать. Например, `session.save_path` штатно умеет шардироваться по директориям, но это отключает сборщик мусора.

---

Если исходить из условий, что отвязаться от сессии слишком дорого - то можно использовать пару хаков:

- реализовать свой [`SessionHandlerInterface`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php), который не будет делать вообще ничего полезного и использовать его для запросов поисковых роботов вместо дефолтного интерфейса.
- или принудительно завернуть роботов на один [`session_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)